# Reference on a corollary for applying Deduction Theorem multiple times in FOL.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , page 75.

In page 75 of the book , there is a corollary in a paragraph that can be used to apply the **Deduction Theorem** multiple times in a row.

> The new proof of $\Gamma \vdash \mathscr B \to \mathscr C$  (in Proposition 2.4 $\Gamma \vdash \mathscr C$ )
> involves an application of Gen to a wf depending upon a wf $\mathscr E$  of $\Gamma$ only if
> there is an application of Gen in the given proof of $\Gamma, \mathscr B \vdash \mathscr C$  that involves
> the same quantified variable and is applied to a wf that depends upon $\mathscr E$.

But there seems to be no justification/proof about this corollary.I searched online but non of them seem to mention this corollary.Are there any references about this I can read or is it just too trivial?

Here is an failed attempt of mine for justifying this corollary.

1.[Technique for applying deduction multiple times in Mendelson Logic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095524/technique-for-applying-deduction-multiple-times-in-mendelson-logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of the proviso in the Deduction Theorem for predicate logic is to avoid the invalid step of quantifying a variable that is free in $B$, because $P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$ is **not** valid.

As already discussed, we have two derivations: the original one: $\Gamma, B \vdash C$ and the new one: $\Gamma \vdash B \to C$, and the DT gives us instructions how to produce the new one from the original one.

In the proof of **Prop.2.5**, we have to consider the case regarding the use of $\text {Gen}$ in the original derivation.

The text says:

> Finally, suppose that there is some $j < i$ such that $D_i$ is $(\forall x_k)Dj$. By the inductive hypothesis, $\Gamma \vdash B \to D_j$, and, by the hypothesis of the theorem, either $D_j$ does not depend upon $B$ or $x_k$ is not a free variable of $B$.

The two sub-cases are considered and instructions are given for writing the corresponding steps in the new derivation.

In the first sub-case we have $\Gamma \vdash (\forall x_k)D_j$ by $\text {Gen}$. Thus, we have an application of $\text {Gen}$ in the new derivation, corresponding to the application of $\text {Gen}$ in the original one. The application is to $D_j$ that does not depend upon $B$ in the original derivation by induction hypotheses; thus, also the application in the new derivation is to a formula that does not depend upon $B$.

In the second sub-case we have $\Gamma \vdash (\forall x_k)(B \to D_j)$ by $\text {Gen}$, and we supposed that $x_k$ is not free in $B$.

In conclusion, in both sub-cases the applications of $\text {Gen}$ in the new derivation satisfy the condition:

> no application of $\text{Gen}$ to a wf that depends upon $B$ has as its quantified variable a free variable of $B$ [in first sub-case: no dependency; in the second sub-case: $x_k$ not free in $B$].

But this means that **if** in the original derivation there were some application of $\text{Gen}$ to a wf depending upon a wf $E$ of $\Gamma$, then in the new derivation there is a corresponding application of $\text{Gen}$ that involves the same quantified variable and is applied to a wf that depends upon $E$.

This is so because applications of $\text {Gen}$ in the first derivation that are not involved in the derivation of $D_j$ are left unchanged into the new derivation and the new applications of $\text{Gen}$ discussed above generate no new dependencies.